# Time difference between button presses swift

Tags: swift

Right now I'm working on a time clock app that allows the user to punch in/out of work time. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to make that function possible.

In my model I have:

```
struct TimeLog {

var punchInTime: CFAbsoluteTime
var punchOutTime: CFAbsoluteTime
var timeWorked: Double


init (pInTime: CFAbsoluteTime, pOutTime: CFAbsoluteTime) {
    self.punchInTime = pInTime
    self.punchOutTime = pOutTime
    self.timeWorked = pOutTime - pInTime
}

}
```

And in my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func punchInButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

// not sure what actions are needed here to start the "aTimeLog" variable

}
@IBAction func punchOutButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

// not sure what actions are needed here to complete the "aTimeLog" variable

}
```

I'm trying to complete this variable:

```
var aTimeLog = TimeLog(pInTime: //get the punch in time here, pOutTime: //get the punch out time here)
```

And once the variable "aTimeLog" is complete (the punchOutButton is pressed) I want to display a log of all of my "timeWorked" variables.

Forgive me in advance. You might be able to tell I'm just learning programming and Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd  keep a variable in NSUserDefaults - storing the punch in time. Then, when the punch out button is tapped, it fetches the dateTime variable from NSUserDefaults, does the needed calculation and returns the result. This caters for if a user closes the app (punch in time is remembered).

This creates an NSUserDefaults object

```
var punchInTime : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    @IBAction func punchInButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
```

Saves the current time

```
        punchInTime.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "punchInTime")
        punchInTime.synchronize()
    }
    @IBAction func punchOutButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
```

fetches the saved time

```
        punchInTime.objectForKey("punchInTime") as NSDate
```

creates a variable holding the current time so you can compare the two

```
        var currentTime : NSDate = NSDate()
        currentTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(punchInTime) // returns seconds
```

Now you can save the start time, end time and total working time inside, say, a dictionary with the key as the date maybe...

```
    }
```

Then when you want to display all the days worked, simply loop through the dictionary :)

...hope I understood correctly

Comment: this makes sense because I do want punch in time to be remembered even if the app is closed out. I entered the code, but I think I'm confused as to how it works and I'm getting unresolved identifier on "sliderTime" (not sure where that came from) and it's also saying that NSUserDefaults is not convertible to NSDate. On top of that I'm confused on how I might store this in a dictionary. (I want to allow the user to view them in a table view). ...Sorry for my ignorance, I'm wanting to learn anyway I can. :)

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake... corrected. The code above wont work out of the box, you will need to fix and play around with it. I have done a simple example for you at http://pastebin.com/Sv4pSyrA but again, it only solves some of your problems. The only way to learn is to figure it out yourself :) keep at it!

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand how to extract the date from the timeIntervalSinceDate function.

Comment: If you look at the comments in my code, it returns an Int with the number of seconds since the date you provide. There is no date to extract from it. The name "'timeInterval'SinceDate" should also give that away...

Answer (score 1):

As one of the possible solutions, you could alter your init method as follows:

```
initWithStartTime (pInTime: CFAbsoluteTime) 
{
    self.punchInTime = pInTime
}
```

Then add a method like:

```
func workedTimeWithEndTime(pOutTime: CFAbsoluteTime) -> CFAbsoluteTime
{
    return pOutTime - self.punchInTime
}
```

Finally you'll probably want to add "var timeLog: TimeLog!" into your view controller and initialise it in punchInButtonPressed with start time.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your ViewController class a ref to a TimeLog class (why did you choose a struct? works too but just curious).

```
var timeLog: TimeLog?
```

Second of all you want to initialise it with a fresh one every time you punch in

```
@IBAction func punchInButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    self.timeLog = TimeLog(pInTime: now)
}
```

So you initialise only with the pInTime, and the rest of the times are set to 0 / null. Next when you punch out you add the pOutTime and you can calculate the timeWorked.

```
@IBAction func punchOutButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.timeLog == nil) {
        return
    }

    self.timeLog!.punchOut(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent());
    println(self.timeLog!.timeWorked)
}
```

Since we don't use the constructor like you've created it and it needs a new function we need to change your class (use class unless you know why you want a struct).

```
class TimeLog {

var punchInTime: CFAbsoluteTime
var punchOutTime: CFAbsoluteTime
var timeWorked: Double


init (pInTime: CFAbsoluteTime) {
    self.punchInTime = pInTime
    self.punchOutTime = 0
    self.timeWorked = 0
}

func punchOut(pOutTime: CFAbsoluteTime) {
self.punchOutTime = pOutTime
self.timeWorked = self.punchOutTime - self.punchInTime
}

}
```

Comment: when I put in: 

    self.timeLog = TimeLog(pInTime: now)

I get a missing argument for parameter "pOutTime" in the punchInButtonPressed Action.

Comment: not sure why, but I'm still getting a bunch of errors

Comment: I changed some small things because I didn't put the code in Xcode again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// run this on first action/tap
let start = Date()

// then, run this on the second time/interaction, to get the negative elapsed time
// for example: for 0.8 seconds this will return -0.8694559335708618
print("Elapsed time: \(start.timeIntervalSinceNow) seconds")
```